# add icon to button

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a script which works well.

```
<button id="sample_editable_1_new" class="btn sbold green">
    Add New
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
```

I would like to change to using the script below.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Add New", "Create", "Customer", null, new { @class = "btn sbold green", xxx})
```

How do i add the  property?

Comment: You cannot using the `ActionLink()` method. You could create you own HtmlHelper extension method to generate the html or use `<a href="@Url.Action(....)">Add New<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>` (and its html, not a script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a CSS class to append the plus character to the link.

```
.plus-icon:after { content: "\f067"; font-family: 'FontAwesome'; padding-left: 5px; }
```

Then add the class to your action link

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add New", "Create", "Customer", null, new { @class = "btn sbold green plus-icon", xxx})
```

Answer (score 3):

`@Html.ActionLink` generate `<a>` tag if you want to use button you should use either js or change your `button` to `a` tag.

It's better to generate it with `@Url.Action` helper if you don't want any js:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("Create", "Customer")' 
   id="sample_editable_1_new" 
   class="btn sbold green">
   Add New
   <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create", CONTROLLERNAME, null, new { @class= "yourCSSclass"}

Html.ActionLink(link text, action name, controller name, route values object, html attributes object)

Html.ActionLink(
"Create New",
"Create",
CONTROLLERNAME,
null,
new { @class= "yourCSSclass", @style= "width:100px; color: red;" }
)
```

Comment: Answers should provide explanation and code, not just code.